# Express get url is wrong

Tags: javascript, express, axios

I am sending an axios request to an express url "getstatus" - on my local development everything is fine, but once the files are on a server there is still my localhost in the url path.

```
this.$axios.get('api/getstatus', {
}).then(function (response) {
})
.catch(function (error) {
});

app.get('/getstatus', async (req, res) => {
  // stuff happening
})
```

-> ok on localhost
-> error on sever: Request URL: http://localhost:3000/api/getstatus

Why is my local development url still getting used? it should be http://myserver.com/api/getstatus

Comment: Add a leading `/` to the request  - `/api/getstatus`

Comment: Where do you set the baseUrl ? Or can you just use the complete URL there without the relative URL ?

Comment: adding the "/" does not solve the problem, I will try to set the url as a variable next

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the axios get request should be `/api/getstatus` not `api/getstatus`

Another thing is you should set an API_URL variable in your dot env file and on development set it to localhost and on your server set it to your server URL.

something like this

```
this.$axios.get(`${process.env.API_URL}/api/getstatus`, {
}).then(function (response) {
   // Code here
})
catch(function (error) {
   // Error code here
});
```

Comment: adding the "/" does not solve the problem, I will try to set the url as a variable next

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below code change to use the full url in the `get` request. If it works you can parameterize the `myserver.com`

```
this.$axios.get('http://myserver.com/api/getstatus', {
    }).then(function (response) {
})
.catch(function (error) {
});
```